# Browsersync middleware: Redirect from a post request

Tags: node.js, express, browser-sync

We are using browsersync in development. For a payment confirmation, the payment provider posts back to a predefined url.

The problem is, that Browsersync only displays `Cannot POST /payment/success`.

So I was thinking about writing a middleware that takes the POST request and redirects to the same URL as a GET request. The problem is, I'm not sure if this is possible with browser sync. When I try to call `res.redirect('/')` it throws an error:

```
    browserSync.init
        server:
            baseDir: "...."
            index: "/statics/master.html"
            middleware: [
                modRewrite(['!\\.\\w+$ /statics/master.html [L]']),
                (req, res, next) ->
                    res.redirect('/') # this throws a TypeError: res.redirect is not a function
            ]
```

> 1. Why is `res.redirect` not defined? I thought browser sync is based on express?
> 2. How could I access the body of the post request? `req.body` returns `undefined`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

browserSync uses [Connect](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect) for the middleware and doesn't share the same api as Express it seems.

For a redirect you can at least do the following:

```
res.writeHead(301, {Location: url});
res.end();
```

Have a look at their documentation for accessing the request body. The section in `Middleware` regarding body parsing may yield some results for you.